# Do work on N numbers of strings at a time from a List<string>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` that contains `N` strings.

And i need to work on `NN` strings at a time then on the last couple strings which not equals to `NN`.

Example:

```
List<string> xList; //Contains 300 string
int N = 100;
int count = //Number of 100s in xList > Couldn't figure it out yet
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < = count; i++)
{
    var vList = xList.Skip(counter).Take(N);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vList.ToArray()));
    counter += N;
}
```

Now what if `xList` contains `350`?

Is there any easier way for this to be done?

Comment: What do you mean `Number of 100s in xList`, can you elaborate ?

Comment: if `xList` contains 300 strings then `count` will be 3

Comment: if xList contains 300, count is 3.  What is count if xList contains 350?  3 or 4?

Comment: He wants to show the string list in chunks of 100, and the reminder as well, see my answer below. There is no need of `count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified version with less variables **and loops**:

```
List<string> xList; //Contains 350 string
int N = 100;

for (int i = 0; i <= xList.Count; i += N)
{
    var vList = xList.Skip(i).Take(N);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vList.ToArray()));
    counter += N;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, change the `100` magic number in the for loop to use the `N` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> xList; //Contains 300 string
int N = 100;
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < = xList.Count; i++)
{
    var vList = xList.Skip(counter).Take(N);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vList.ToArray()));
    counter += N;
}
```

Something like the above?

Comment: This works but, it repeats the `MessageBox` 300 times.